# A scheduled refresh created by Abc person failed

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a query embedded in Google sheet

when I am refreshing it manually its works fine but when I am scheduling it it fails with below error

Any suggestions?

Query failed

A scheduled refresh created by Abc person failed.

Something's wrong. Please try again later To view this query, visit BigQuery. If you do not have access, then relay the following Job ID to someone who has access:
sheets_dataconnector_scheduled_xxxxxx

If you think this is an error, please
send feedback
now